# Typing an overloaded class method

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics, typescript-types

I need to write a wrapper around a method `foo` that is overloaded by parameter type.

UPDATE: `A` extends `B`

UPDATE2: [TS playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?strictFunctionTypes=false&ts=4.2.3#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDOwBOBLAdgcygHykwFcBbAIwlXyjIHtaAbCAQ0wG4AoUSKAIQVjUAFEICUCAHxQA3lAAmzYMwBcyNFmxso6OauLlKUAL6jOHLMEoAzZgGNoAcRkcorq-SEAPPaQqoANFAgAPyqMKKqKBg4nK5Q7rRePgYBQaF8EXycRhwctrSYKFDYEMBOiGKq5VJC0i5xCapJhL6UgSFh4vBSIFDBUADkvehI8hBWWBByA1CqAAYAJNKeRnP%209W70Td4tKe3pvF01R1C18ooqUABEAEostsAAcrRyEFeBOqqeUACkUABMJg4JjM%20UKwBk8XoxgEJTKYlBBSKzAECSEAEZAlcABboK6mKAAekJami2DySIhZFRHkxpxOZwUSlUVyQtBI0CZzHe2l0AJMBOJNFyYKK2AA6qhmGBIFQKic6nEoKKIbIEjDEHCHAiNlBUKUiKhMFAADwAFSgEE8lkwclGcAIvAkzX0fn2qjNmQtVptdsE-SiGlmfEkziVStFjAgADoGLRsF5TLqlfrgIbjWjPO0k0qckYgA)

```
const getFoo: {
   foo(x: number, y?: A): A;
   foo(x: number, y?: B): B;
}
```

In my TS IntelliSense-enabled IDE, `const a = foo(1, {} as A)` is of type `A`, and `const b = foo(1, {} as B})` is of type `B`. So, the overloading is working.

My wrapper function:

```
const fooWrapper = () => {
  const { foo } = getFoo();
  return {
     modifiedFoo: <T extends A | B>(x: number, y?: T) => {
        // my code
        return foo(x, y);
     }
  }
```

However, `const c = modifiedFoo(1, {} as A)` is of type `B`, instead of `A` as you would expect.

Trying to add a return type to `modifiedFoo`:

```
modifiedFoo: <T extends A | B>(x: number, y?: T):
  T extends A
  ? A
  : T extends B
  ? B
  : never
```

fixes the return type of `modifiedFoo`, but it causes a compiler issue in the modifiedFoo definition on the line `return foo(x, y)`, stating

```
Type 'B' is not assignable to type 'T extends A ? A : T extends B ? B : never'
Type 'A' is not assignable to type 'T extends A ? A : T extends B ? B : never'
```

Its very odd to me that I can call `return foo(x, y as A)` to get `modifiedFoo` to always return `A`, or `return foo(x, y as B)` to get `modifiedFoo` to always return `B`, but with generics `returnFoo(x, y)` with y being type `T` does not return the correct type, unless I add the explicit return type definition which causes the compiler error.

Comment: Is 
```
const getFoo: {
   foo(x: number, y?: A): A;
   foo(x: number, y?: B): B;
}
```
correct?
I am having difficulty in replicating this in ts playground.

Comment: It is, I can't find the definition for it as it is coming from an external library. But the type of getFoo is as you say.

Comment: Does A extend B or B extend A?

Comment: Sorry - A extends B. I'll update the original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer with explanation:

```
type OverloadedParams<T> = T extends { (...o: infer U1): any; (...o: infer U2): any } ? U1 | U2 : never;

type OverloadedReturn<T, U> = Extract<
 T extends {
     (...args: infer A1): infer R1;
     (...args: infer A2): infer R2;
 } ? U extends A1 ? [U, R1] : U extends A2 ? [U, R2] : never : never, [U, any]
>[1];

const gWrapper = () => {
    const { foo } = getG();
    return <T extends OverloadedParams<G["foo"]>>(...args: T): OverloadedReturn<G["foo"], T> => {
        return foo(args[0], args[1]);
    }
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?strictFunctionTypes=false&ts=4.2.3&ssl=36&ssc=2&pln=15&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDOwBOBLAdgcygHykwFcBbAIwlXyjIHtaAbCAQ0wG4AoUSKAIQVjUAFEICUCAHxQA3lAAmzYMwBcyNFmxso6OauLlKUAL6jOHLMEoAzZgGNoAcRkcorq-SEAPPaQqoANFAgAPyqMKKqKBg4nK5Q7rRePgYBQaF8EXycRhwctrSYKFDYEMBOiGKq5VJC0i5xCapJhL6UgSFh4vBSIFDBUADkvehI8hBWWBByA1CqAAYAJNKeRnP%209W70Td4tKe3pvF01R1C18ooqUABEAEostsAAcrRyEFeBOqqeUACkUABMJg4JjMXHA0AA8gA3SgMWjMV5yAAKzFQzBISAAPAAVKSIbFQCCeSyYOSjWRCAB01NoqiwVkMAFUAIyZVggLRUml0zAMqiM-5szC9Ix9KAs6gC2aECAw1BmAD0CqgAHVaKgANZIME8aGw%20GIu7AIioTDMnGBRl4qAAUWJaIemJcBKJJLJzjiri5lNR2CQPL5sFZAcMN2ZsU93t9-u0vMMMEFIaoN3%20sVF-UZhOJEFJoxgzLFAG1GYEwwBdaWZ10590JoslqApit6WWGFtywLFwLssscCSF5llxXKgAitAgSEwA2AUAA7uqNTrIXK4QipkaTZh-hbxdaoC7s7mPZHqT7UH6k0HMvTQ%20GNl7T9HLwnr3Hk6mXOnxVm3XmC-0w0rH8azzf4xRTaVMFbKh20oMx8kKGdsBVNEwEgKgKhOOpPQQopZASYwBBKMoxAjVxUFKTcoBxYCjz1VBV0RFE0QxTEHELK4EiuMsJAkKNzxjbFMnoxj10o01zXYzj6G4wJcUkY9PXI8TMHiDxo0LAAGMtuwEgcy1Me8ciMIA)

The key is getting the parent type of the overloaded argument type (not the subtype) and associating it with the appropriate return type using the definition of the overloaded functions.

What I still don't understand, and why this took so long to solve, is why

```
type OverloadedReturn<T, U> =  T extends {
     (...args: infer A1): infer R1;
     (...args: infer A2): infer R2;
 } ? U extends A1 ? R1 : U extends A2 ? R2 : never : never;
```

doesn't work.